# Caracteres raros en interfaz de Netbeans 8.1

Tags: interfaz-gráfica, netbeans-8.1

Alguien sabe por que Netbeans 8.1 en su panel de la parte superior no muestra ningún idioma ya sea ingles, español, etc. En cambio muestra caracteres extraños.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente reinstalando la aplicación, eliminando la cache desde Appdata, y eliminado toda carpeta relacionada con Netbeans, pero siempre que instalo aparece igual.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.